# Subtract two ranges and clear the contents from result

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to subtract RangeA - RangeA+offset to get a new range. After this i need to clear all the values within it. My problem is that the variable columnrange is empty and i'm unable to realize what i'm doing wrong.

```
Dim rng1 As String
Dim rangeA As Range
Dim columnrange As Range
Dim clearrange As Range

rng1 = TextBoxA.Value

If Not IsNull(RangeboxA.Value) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rangeA = Sheets("Plan1").Range(RangeboxA.Value)
        rangeA.Select
        Selection.Copy
        rangeA.Offset(0, rng1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        columnrange = rangeA.Resize(rangeA.Rows.Count, rangeA.Columns.Count + rng1).Value
        columnrange.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    If rangeA Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Verificar informação A"

    End If
```

Comment: When you say subtract RangeA-(RangeA+offset) do you mean "the values in RangeA" - "the values in (RangeA+offset)"? Clear the values within 'it', the new range?

Comment: Subtract RangeA - (RangeA+offset) and this difference will give me a new range and i want to erase all values in this new range.

Comment: For example: 
E2:H2 - B2:E2 = B2:D2 (New range)

I want to erase values from B2:D2.

Comment: What is the expected format of the string in rng1 that comes from the textbox? Per your example above, are we getting an input of the string "B2:E2"?

Comment: rng1 its a number. RangeA its like B2:E2

Comment: A number that represents what? The starting column of the second range? How are you getting E2:H2?

Comment: So you start with B2:E2 (RangeA from RangeboxA.Value) and you also have the user input a number to offset the columns by (rng1 from TextBoxA.Value). You want to select RangeA, copy it, and paste it at RangeA offset by rng1. Then you want to delete the values from the original RangeA location? Why not just use Cut+Paste?

Comment: I have to input a range in rangeboxA and a number in texboxA. 
rangeboxA value goes to rangeA and the number goes to rng1.
rng1 is used to offset rangeA. If i use my exemple to answer you, B2:D2 is the input in rangeboxA and 3 is the input in textboxA.

Comment: You want the offset to push both ends of the range? IOW B2:D2 offset by 3 = E2:G2? Place the B2:D2 values to E2:G2 and then delete B2:D2?

Comment: That is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This code moves a user-defined range by a user-defined amount.

```
Sub RemoveRangeOverlap()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")
    Dim rngOffset As Integer
    Dim rangeA As Range, rangeB As Range
    Dim cellRange() As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    rngOffset = CInt(TextBoxA.Value)

    If RangeBoxA.Value <> "" Then
        Set rangeA = ws.Range(RangeBoxA.Value) 'Set old range

        cellRange = Split(CStr(RangeBoxA.Value), ":") 'Set start/ending cells
        ReDim Preserve cellRange(LBound(cellRange) To UBound(cellRange))

        Set rangeB = ws.Range(ws.Range(cellRange(0)).Offset(0, rngOffset), _
            ws.Range(cellRange(1)).Offset(0, rngOffset)) 'set new range

        rangeA.Copy rangeB 'copy new range
        Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy 'remove marching ants

        If rangeA.Columns.Count <= rngOffset Then 'remove old values
            rangeA.Clear
        Else: ws.Range(ws.Range(cellRange(0)), _
              ws.Range(cellRange(1)).Offset(0, rngOffset - rangeA.Columns.Count)).Clear
        End If
    Else: MsgBox "Missing target range input.", vbCritical, "Insufficient Data"
    End If

ErrHandle:
    If Err.Number = 438 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid range format in range input box." & vbNewLine & _
            "Proper range format example: A1:A1", vbCritical, "Error 438"
    ElseIf Err.Number = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Only numbers may be input as the range offset amount", _
            vbCritical, "Error 13: Type Mis-match"
    ElseIf Err.Number = 5 Then Exit Sub
    Else: Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### How the code works:

**The first thing we have set up is information control from user-defined values. To accomplish this (which can also be done with `If Then` statements to prevent the errors from ever occurring in the first place) I've included an error handling line at the end. We know what 3 errors we expect to get depending on what the user provides us with.**

- Error 438 will occur if the user tries to set RangeBoxA's value as a non-range value.
- Error 13 will occur if the user tries to input anything that isn't a number as the offset value.
- Error 5 will occur because I'm bad at error handling and I'm not sure why it's occuring.. It loops my error statement at the end after whichever error is thrown (being a non-vba error).

**Next we split up the range supplied by the user into two 'cells'. Using this we can apply some simple math to show where the copy destination will be as well as delete the proper amount of old range values.**

- If the number of columns is greater than the user supplied offset, then the new and old ranges will overlap. Some simple math will remove the old cells while preserving the new one's
- If the number of columns is less than the user supplied offset, delete all of the old cells because they won't be overlapping.

---

***Let me know if this works for you.***

Comment: I think that your code is cutting the range and copying after offset. If i do this all formulas linked to this range will remain linked, even after apply the offset. I'm trying to avoid this, thats whey i'm trying do copy and erase the  cells.

Comment: So you just want the values to move, not the formulae? I changed the code to reflect only pasting values, not formulas.

Comment: Correct. I want to move some values through the time, like postpone 6 months, so i do want it to be linked.

Comment: See if the change I made to the code works for you... I'm really confused.

Comment: Let me explain my worksheet. I have incomes divided by months and cells linked to them calculating the total sum. If i want to postpone a specific income, like 6 months, i cant just cut because the linked cells will remain the same. So i have to copy, paste and erase the cells that i copied to avoid values in the wrong month.

Comment: I think I understand what you want now. Give me a sec, the posted code isn't what you want.

Comment: @Ygor I've updated the code to perform as we discussed.

Comment: its not working. I got an error of object required in this line:

Comment: Else: Err.Raise Err.Number

Comment: comment out the top line that says `On Error GoTo ErrHandle` and tell me where the error comes up.

Comment: I deleted the errhandle and now is working well. I really appreciate your help. Thank You!